# jQuery.each() iteration through php output

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, cloud, zooming, each

I am new to jQuery but have a question I hope some of you can help with... I have tried several examples on this site but can't seem to figure out a solid solution. Each link is completely unique by #id. I am looking to iterate through the generated(php) ids and append a universal .click() event. I am using cloud-zoom (jQuery). The kicker is that when I use ".tagImg" as the class selector, it will open the image(link) in a new window. But when I specify a specific id(#tagImage-0) the script works perfectly. Therefore I need a way to iterate through the unknown amount of images to make this work correctly.

Extremely basic skeleton:

```
<div class="tagImg">
  <a id="tagImage-0" href="big0.img"><img src="/images/thumb0.jpg"></a>
  <a id="tagImage-1" href="big1.img"><img src="/images/thumb1.jpg"></a>
  <a id="tagImage-2" href="big2.img"><img src="/images/thumb2.jpg"></a>
  <a id="tagImage-3" href="big3.img"><img src="/images/thumb3.jpg"></a>
  <a id="tagImage-4" href="big4.img"><img src="/images/thumb4.jpg"></a>
  <a id="tagImage-5" href="big5.img"><img src="/images/thumb5.jpg"></a>
</div>
```

Works per link:

```
$("#tagImage-0").click(function() {
    // Process some code
});
```

Opens link in new window (keep in mind, using cloud-zoom):

```
$(".tagImg").click(function() {
    // Process some code
}):
```

Used this but did not work?:

```
$("#tagImage > a").click(function() {
    // Process some code
});
```

If required, I can provide some more specific code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector `#tagImage > a` means: all immediate descendants of element `#tagImage` which are also anchors. No elements can match that description. I think what you meant to do was:

```
$('.tagImg > a').click(...);
```

Basically, you had a typo :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
$(".tagImg > a").click(function() {
      //process some code
}
```

What the above does is reference the "a" elements inside of the "tagImg" class referenced on the div element.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(".tagImg > a").click(function() {
    // Process some code
});
```

Comment: It should be .tagImg rather than #tagImg

Comment: @rajasaur Oh, my miss, fixed.